# Нужно ли обособлять запятыми союз "и"? Объясните, пожалуйста, почему - надо или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Я долго думала о том, как помочь вам решить эту сложную задачу, и, кажется, я знаю ответ!

Comment: Союзы не обособляются. В принципе. Сформулируйте вопрос корректно.

Answer (score 3):

*[Я долго думала о том, (как помочь вам решить эту сложную задачу)], и, кажется, я знаю ответ!*

Запятая **перед** "и" разделяет части **ССП**:

***Я*** долго **думала** <…>, **и** <…> **я знаю**...

Другими двумя запятыми выделено **вводное** слово:

*…и, **кажется**, я знаю...*

Answer (score 2):

1) Союз И не обособляется, а выделяется запятыми. Первая запятая разделяет СПП и простое предложение в составе сложного предложения. Вторая запятая связана с обособлением вводного слова КАЖЕТСЯ.

2) Это, конечно, вводное  слово.

С точки зрения морфологии, вводные слова соотносятся с именами, наречиями и глаголами, в частности личными формами глагола:  кажется, видишь ли, представьте себе, думаю, полагаем, говорят, рассказывают. Выражение "мне кажется"  является вводным предложением, и только "мне кажется, что..." - это сказуемое в безличном предложении.

Comment: Я вижу, вы любите вкусно поесть.
Я вижу, что вы любите вкусно поесть.

Здесь в первом варианте идея "вводности" тоже настолько сильна, что отменяет подлежащее со сказуемым?

Comment: Думаю, что да. Особенно, если переставить вводную часть: Вы, я вижу, любите вкусно поесть. Конструкции такого вида встречаются нередко и всегда вызывают вопросы. А идея вводности все эти проблемы легко решает.

Comment: А авторский подход здесь возможен? Поставив запятую, я делаю акцент на втором глаголе, отправляя в тень первый - вместе с другими элементами вводного предложения, которое становится присказкой типа "вроде бы". А не поставив запятую, я настаиваю на реальности действия первого глагола (со смыслом как в варианте с "что", но укороченно). В нашем примере: до размышлений казалось (так подразумевается), что не знаю, а после них тоже кажется, но другое (знаю).

Comment: Насколько эта "вводность" условна -  следует ли она однозначно из самого языка или так договорились её распознавать по внешним признакам (здесь "что"), зафиксировав правилами? Я в случае с глаголом (или вводным предложением) вижу чёткие границы не в наличии/отсутствии "что" (которое даже раположено вне этой части), а в добавках вроде "как" (как я вижу, как мне кажется) или перестановках, которые превращают вводное предложение в "присказку".

Comment: Вводные слова относятся ко второму плану речи - это их важная особенность, а в остальном это те же наречия, имена, глаголы, и формально с очень похожим значением.  Тем не менее семантика модифицированная: КАЖЕТСЯ - это чувство или ощущение, МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ - начальная оценка, МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ, ЧТО - это уже продуманное суждение. И грамматика языка подстраивается под эти разные значения: вводное слово, вводное предложение, обычное предложение первого плана речи.

Comment: В приведенном предложении  долго что-то обдумывалось, но уверенности в конечном выводе нет, только  чувство или ощущение, что понял, разобрался. И именно такой смысл имеет в виду автор, используя слово КАЖЕТСЯ, в противном случае он использовал бы другую форму.

Answer (score 0):

Союз "и" как таковой не обособляют, хотя чисто внешне может так выглядеть. Могут обособляться примыкающие к нему обороты. В данном случае я бы не поставил запятой *после* "и": слово "кажется" здесь не вводное - это сказуемое безличного предложения, логически связанного с предыдущим и присоединённым через союз "и". "(Я подумала)..., и (теперь) мне кажется, (что) я знаю ответ". Опускание "мне" не должно здесь приводить к появлению запятой, поскольку безличное предложение от этого не разрушается.